# Anchor tag link not working on IE11

Tags: anchor, internet-explorer-11

The anchor tag link doesn't work only on IE11 but works on all other versions of IE.

Here is my code:

```
    <a class="fancy_button" id="A2" 
href="xxx.asp" runat="server" style="text-decoration: none;" target="_blank">
<span style="background-color: #FF0000;width: 100px">FANCY BUTTON
                                        </span></a>
```

I tried replacing anchor tag with input element button. But no use.

Please suggest how to make it work on IE11.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: <a class="fancy_button" id="A2" href="xxx.asp"
                                runat="server" style="text-decoration: none;" target="_blank"><span style="background-color: #FF0000;
                                    width: 100px">FANCY BUTTON</span></a>

Comment: Does it work if you remove `runat="server"` or change the website to http://www.microsoft.com ?

Comment: how to change website to microsoft.com?

Comment: change the `href="xxx.asp"` to `href="http://www.microsoft.com"`

Comment: Both dint work.Please let know how i should proceed

Comment: Try removing all of the styling and see if it works, then add the stylings one by one and test it.  i.e. try this code first `<a id="A2" 
href="xxx.asp">FANCY BUTTON</a>`

Comment: No luck..removal of all styles made no use

Comment: wow.  That should have worked.  It's just a basic link.  Do you get any errors?

Comment: No errors.The link showed up.But when I click nothing happens.

Comment: if you right click on the link and copy and past the url to the browser, will it open?

Comment: the words FANCY BUTTON show in blue color.But when i take mouse on it ,the cursor doesnot change.It is the same.So nothing happend when right click or left click :(

Answer (score 0):

Use the "name" attribute instead of (or on top of -) the "id" attribute :

```
<a class="fancy_button" id="A2" name="A2" ...>
```